# Is it possible to have linked n-spheres in any other space other than $\Bbb R^{n+2}$?

Tags: manifolds, geometric-topology, low-dimensional-topology

Two $n$-spheres can be linked in infinitely many ways in $\Bbb R^{n+2}$? Is it possible to have two n-spheres tamely linked in $\Bbb R^{n+1}$?

Comment: [Closely related](https://mathoverflow.net/q/52692/30186)

Comment: Your question does not contain enough detail to be answerable: You need to state what you defined as "linked sphere" (as you might have learned from the Mathoverflow discussion, there different notions here). Also, state what kind of spheres you are working with (smooth, piecewise-linear, topological, tame topological). There is one quite deep theorem in topology about pairs of codimension 1 spheres in $S^{n+1}$ called "Annulus Theorem": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annulus_theorem. Maybe this is what you are after.

Comment: Moishe, I am aware that there are different notions of linking and the category (smooth VS PL ) plays a difference but I kept the question open like this because I want to hear what people say in different context. I do not agree that I should ask the question the way you suggested. There is no one way to ask question on this forum. The link you provided above is not relevant at all, but thanks for trying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’m not sure exactly what you are looking for since you don’t wish to limit the notion of linking.  Would you consider two Alexander horned spheres in $\mathbb R^3$ whose ‘arms’ are ‘interlocked’ at the first level of iteration but with distinct Cantor sets at the end of the construction to be linked? If so, that’s your answer.  If not, please tell us more about the question.

Comment: Greg, that is one good answer, thank you, but I would prefer to see also a tame example (if there is one).

Comment: @Steve  The point is, I think, that you need to tell me the category (or homology theory) in which you want them linked.  The example I gave you consists of spheres homologically linked in Cech theory but not in singular theory.  If you require the spheres be linked in singular homology theory that might be hard (if not impossible).  I’m kind of lazy so it’s hard for me to get the motivation to work on this unless you give me more of a hope to satisfy you.

Comment: that is fair. So I care mostly for PL or the smooth categories with more preference toward the PL category. I also care for tame examples.

Comment: @Steve The notion of ‘tame’ here seems to be key.  In the example I chose spheres for which there was no ambient continuous homeomorphism to round spheres and then used a weak homology theory.  To come up with fancier examples why not pick, tame spheres which are not PL-tame (not ambient homeomorphic to round spheres by PL maps) and then use a weak homology theory to test linking.  This is not my area of expertise, being a wild soul, and may be gibberish, but seems to me to have a chance of working.

Comment: Thanks Greg for your answers. I am pretty sure this is something people have worked on before and I was wondering what is known in this area. Thanks anyway.